# How can you make multiple javafx Event handlers simply?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, lambda

Most sources I've seen dealing with JavaFX inputs uses inline lamdba expressions.
Like:

```
button.setOnMouseClicked((new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
         public void handle(MouseEvent event) { 
            text.setText("Clicked!")  
         } 
      }));
```

This seems like quite a clean way to do things, but could I use something that allows me to document code better?

I would like to get rid of the inline methods.

I've been hardcoding a simple GUI and would want to either make a method called makeEventHandlers() that makes all event handers I need. Or make the methods I need to handle the events in different methods.

1:

```
public class GUI{
   Button a;
   Text b;

   private void makeGUI()
   {
      b = new Text();
      a.addEventHander(event -> handleButtonA())
   }

   private void handleButtonA() 
   {
      b.setText("Text set!");
   }

}
```

Comment: `a.setOnAction(event -> handleButtonA())` ← I do that all the time.  Similarly, ChangeListeners can be shortened to `dropDown.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((o, oldVal, newVal) -> updateSomethingUsing(oldVal, newVal));`.

Comment: don't understand your question - just follow the suggestion by @VGR ...